# How connect with postgres using ssh tunnel?

Tags: postgresql, prisma

How I can connect with my database via ssh tunnel?
Link for ssh tunnel look like:

```
postgresql+ssh://sshUser:sshPassword@sshServerUrl/dbUser:dbPassword@dbUrl:dbPort/dbName
```

Can Prisma handle this format?

Answer (score 1):

If you can connect to the database machine through ssh, do so first.

```
ssh -L 5432:localhost:5432 database-machine.org
```

This makes an assumption your database listens on localhost on your server and listens to port 5432. Also makes an assumption you have a free port 5432 on your machine.

So, how it works: the first 5432 on the string is the port you open on localhost, the middle part localhost means the hostname the PostgreSQL is listening to (can also be 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0) and the last number is the port the server is listening to.

When you get this running, from the same machine you can modify your connection string to:

```
postgresql://user:pass@localhost:5432/database
```

And it should work.

Comment: Postgres listens by default port TCP/5432.